# onClick method is not called from .xml binding expression with dataBinding

Tags: kotlin, android-databinding

I'm trying to call a function which is in the "MainActivity.kt" from "content_main.xml" by usage of a binding expression in the onClick (what are these actually called, attribute?) of a button.

Problem is, they never get called when I press eighter of the buttons.

That's how the code passage looks like in the "content_main.xml" file (I've left out unnecessary code for better readability):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<data>
    <variable
        name="viewModel"
        type="com.ronnabyte.ntatools.model.FuelViewModel" />

    <variable
        name="activity"
        type="com.ronnabyte.ntatools.MainActivity" />
</data>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    ...

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/clear_required_fuel_btn"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton.Icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="@{()->activity.clearRequiredFuel()}"
        android:text="@string/clear_fuel_on_board"
        app:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_delete_24"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/required_fuel_ed"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/required_fuel_ed"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/required_fuel_ed" />

    ...

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/clear_remaining_fuel_btn"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="@{()->activity.clearRemainingFuel()}"
        android:text="@string/clear_fuel_on_board"
        app:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_delete_24"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/remaining_fuel_ed"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/remaining_fuel_ed"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/remaining_fuel_ed" />

    ...

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And the code in the "MainActivity.kt":

```
package com.ronnabyte.ntatools

import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.view.Menu
import android.view.MenuItem
import androidx.activity.viewModels
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil
import androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleOwner
import com.ronnabyte.ntatools.databinding.ActivityMainBinding
import com.ronnabyte.ntatools.model.FuelViewModel

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
private val viewModel: FuelViewModel by viewModels()

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main)

    setSupportActionBar(binding.toolbar)

    binding.fab.setOnClickListener {
        viewModel.calculateFuelUplift()
    }
}

override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu)
    return true
}

override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    return when (item.itemId) {
        R.id.action_settings -> true
        else -> super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }
}

fun clearRequiredFuel() {
    Log.d("MainActivity", "ClearRequiredFuel has been called.")
    binding.contentMain.apply {
        requiredFuelUpliftTv.text = ""
        requiredFuelEd.text.clear()
        requiredFuelEd.requestFocus()
    }
}

fun clearRemainingFuel() {
    Log.d("MainActivity", "ClearRemainingFuel has been called.")
    binding.contentMain.apply {
        requiredFuelUpliftTv.text = ""
        remainingFuelEd.text.clear()
        requiredFuelEd.requestFocus()
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated, many thanks.

Edit: here is the gradle file:

```
plugins {
id 'com.android.application'
id 'kotlin-android'
id 'kotlin-kapt'
}

android {
compileSdk 31

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.ronnabyte.ntatools"
    minSdk 26
    targetSdk 31
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android- optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

buildFeatures {
    dataBinding true
}

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = '1.8'
}

}

dependencies {

implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.2'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.4.0'
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.4.0"
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.4.0'
```

}

Comment: What if move these methods to `ViewModel` and in `MainActivity` subscribe on `ViewModel` LiveData?

Comment: Even if I would know how to do that, wouldn't that be against the viewModel architecture, which says the viewModel should not be aware about views? I'm setting the views in those two functions...  Apologies, I'm rather new to this.

Comment: I think, my assumption is wrong. But concerning to `ViewModel` it wouldn't be wrong. You will have `LiveData` or `MutableStateFlow` in `ViewModel` and set it's value there. Then in `MainActivity` you will subscribe to this value from `ViewModel`. When data in `ViewModel` will change (LiveData or MutableStateFlow will change it's value), subscriber will also reflect changes (`requiredFuelUpliftTv.text = ""`, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem why the `binding.activity = this` wasn't working. `binding` is of type `ActivityMainBinding`, but the variable `activity` was defined in the `content_main.xml` instead of `activity_main.xml`.

That's why it couldn't be found on the binding, hence turning red all the time.

Answer (score 0):

make these little changes to your code:

```
private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
private val viewModel: FuelViewModel by viewModels()

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
binding
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater) //<--
    setContentView(binding.root) //<--
    setSupportActionBar(binding.toolbar)
```

Comment: This doesn't work, the code runs trough, but the function is still not called when I press the button(s).

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in your `onCreate` method:

```
binding.activity = this
```

Demo code below:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main)
        // without this line, test() will not called
        binding.activity = this
    }

    fun test() {
        Log.d("test", "test")
    }
}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="activity"
            type="com.example.myapplication.MainActivity" />
    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="@{() -> activity.test()}"
            android:text="Hello World!"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't work, I get "Unresolved reference" on the activity.

Comment: Which variable is unresolved? I wrote a demo to test, and it worked. Please check my edited answer.

Comment: Many thanks for looking into it, much appreciated. When I start a new project and use the code you provided, it works perfectly as you said. But when I try the "binding.activity = this" line in my project, then ".activity" turns red with the tooltip "Unresolved reference: activity". But "binding" is of the exact same type as with the example that is working, which is the type "private final lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding". I cleaned and rebuilt the project with no luck. I'll try to include the gradle file, so you can have a look if you have time. Thank you very much.